# Stuck while base64.encodestring with an error for python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64

While using `Python3`, I am trying to encode string to the DataFrame I am stuck with the error :

> "expected bytes-like object, not str', 'occurred at index "

When I ran the code in `Python2` it working fine like

```
user_profile['email_verification'] = user_profile.apply(lambda row : urllib.quote_plus(base64.encodestring(row['email'])+","+base64.encodestring(str(row['customer_id']))),axis=1)
```

But the same is not working in `Python3` and keeps on giving the error
code is

```
user_profile['email_verification'] = user_profile.apply(lambda row : urllib.parse.quote_plus(base64.encodestring(row['email'])+","+base64.encodestring(str(row['customer_id']))),axis=1)
```

This keeps on giving the same error like

> "TypeError: ('expected bytes-like object, not str', 'occurred at index 237559')"

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

base64.encodestring is deprecated, try encode the string as bytes object with .encode() and then use base64.b64encode

```
user_profile['email_verification'] = user_profile.apply(lambda row : urllib.parse.quote_plus(str(base64.b64encode(str(row['email']).encode()),'utf-8')+","+str(base64.b64encode(str(row['customer_id']).encode()),'utf-8'),axis=1)
```

Comment: Got stuck with the error

TypeError: ("can't concat str to bytes", 'occurred at index 357918')

Comment: Do you want it as 'b64 string , b64 string' or the whole thing as b64 string? I changed my answer to convert them to strings so they can be concatenated

Answer (score 0):

You have to get clear of your data first. The error says that the function is receiving a string object.
smth like: 'abc'
A byte object looks different
smth like: b'\xe8\x03'